# Wireshark arp packets

Tags: networking, wireshark, arp

In wireshark, after capturing some arp packets, what is the significance of all 1's in the destination field. of an Ethernet II frame?

Answer (score 9):

ARP request packets are sent to the ethernet broadcast address FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF (or all 1s if you're looking at in binary). This will flood the packet throughout the network so that the correct device will hear it and respond with its IP address.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol